# how to upload image using mulipartentity in android?

Tags: java, android

I am using asynktask with MultipartEntity for file upload and i got the success MSG from server side but my image is not being upload into the server even   i am getting success response any help, i searched on internet i could not get any relevant  answer on that my code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resume_upload_activity);
    ivAttachment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
    bUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    tvFileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
    ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //on attachment icon click
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v== bUpload){

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            new  UploadImageTask().execute();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("image/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            try {
                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

            if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}




private class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(FileUpload.this);
    ByteArrayBody bab;
    String response;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog.setTitle("Uploading Image");
        dialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            Log.d(TAG,"Url Open");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //connection.connect();

            String reqHead = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("connection","Keep-Alive"+reqHead);
            //Header header = new Header();

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            File file= new File(selectedFilePath);
            //file.toString(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
            FileBody fileBody= new FileBody(file);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image");


            entity.addPart("image",fileBody);
            entity.addPart("Some other String to send",new StringBody("something"));

            connection.addRequestProperty("content-length",entity.getContentLength()+"");
            connection.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(),entity.getContentType().getValue());

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
            os.close();
            connection.connect();

            if(connection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                return readStream(connection.getInputStream());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream inputStream) {

        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(line);
            }
            response = builder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (response.equals("success")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Files Uploaded..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

any my URL is some think like that is URL call is correct?

```
http://somurl.com/live?header={"cameraId":"A_IVIS5045C1","encoderType":0}
```

Comment: check filebody size in your side, if it is valid then ask server side guy to fix issue

Comment: @srinu file body size is just an image, if i used this url using post man i got image but if i used this url from android the image was not uplaod

Comment: are you sending image url like key value pair in postman?

Comment: @srinu i am just using binery and uplaod file.

Comment: refer this https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/

Comment: its not open hasan

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `MultipartEntity` then I will suggest you my library, that I have created for uploading file (with data or without).

Here is the [Git Url](https://github.com/vishalchhodwani1992/httpLibrary)

Add this dependency in your module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.scantity.ScHttpLibrary:ScHttpLibrary:1.0.0'
}
```

add your file into Hashmap:

```
    HashMap<String, File> fileParameters = new HashMap<>();
    fileParameters.put("fileKey", new File(filePath));
```

And execute start execution

```
new HttpRequestResponse(MainActivity.this)
            .setOnResultListener(new HttpRequestResponse.ResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json, String requestCode) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "json=="+json.toString());
                }
            })
            .setUrl("http://requestb.in/11xjkya1")
            .setHeaderParameters(headerParameters) // Optional
            .setStringParameters(stringParameters)
            .setFileParameters(fileParameters)
            .setMethod(HttpRequestResponse.Method.POST)
            .isDialogShown(true, "Loading...")
            .setSocketTimeOut(30)
            .executeMethod();
```

**Note:** This is an asynchronous Task.

Comment: thanks for this but i want to uplaod file using multpart reqeust

Comment: Yes it is multypart. This library using http-mime library for multypart uploading.